# continuous each variable separately and monotonic imply continuous

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous each variable
> separately and monotonic with respect to one variable. Prove that $f$
> is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

My attempt:
Consider $(x_0,y_0)\in\mathbb{R}^2$
Since $f$ is continuous each variable separately $\Rightarrow\forall\epsilon>0$
$$
\begin{cases}
\exists\delta_1>0\quad\text{s.t}\quad\forall x:|x-x_0|< \delta _1\Rightarrow |f(x,y_0)-f(x_0,y_0)|<\epsilon\\
\exists\delta_2>0\quad\text{s.t}\quad\forall y:|y-y_0|< \delta _2\Rightarrow |f(x_0,y)-f(x_0,y_0)|<\epsilon
\end{cases}
$$
If I choose $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$, then from $\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}< \delta$ $$\Rightarrow|x-x_0|< \delta _1 \text{ and } |y-y_0|< \delta _2$$ 
$\Rightarrow |f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)|\leq |f(x,y)-f(x,y_0)|+|f(x,y_0)-f(x_0,y_0)|$ $\hspace{4.4cm} \leq |f(x,y)-f(x,y_0)|+\epsilon$. 
I don't know how to continue and I haven't used the monotonic property of $f$ yet. Can someone give me hints?

Comment: the solution of Chris is hard to understand. Is there any other solution?

Comment: I rewrote the presentation, see if this is useful

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the question supposes:

- $f(x,d)$, as a function of $x$, is continuous non-increasing for some values of $d$ and continuous non-decreasing **for all other values** of $d$
- $f(c,y)$, as a function of $y$, is continuous for all values of $c$

**Now, assume without loss of generality that $f(0,0)=0$. We want to show that $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.**

Let's use a proof by contradiction. What if there were a constant $r>0$ as well as a sequence of points $(x_n,y_n)$ converging to the origin, such that $|f(x_n,y_n)|>r$?

Remember, by the way, that $|f(x_n,y_n)|>r$ is equivalent to saying that either $f(x_n,y_n)<-r$ or $f(x_n,y_n)>r$. This gives us two separate categories to put each point of the sequence $(x_n,y_n)$.

But within each of those categories there are two sub-categories: is $f(X,y_n)$ non-increasing or non-decreasing as a function of $X$? Therefore, we really have four sub-categories.

Now, it must be the case that one of these four sub-categories contains an infinite subsequence $(x_{n_i},y_{n_i})$. It could be more than one sub-category, but it has to be at least one. (Otherwise, if each of the four categories contained only finitely many points, then the whole sequence would have only finitely many points, which would be a contradiction.)

I'm going to assume the sub-category "$f(x_n,y_n)>r$, and $f(X,y_n)$ non-decreasing" has an infinite subsequence. (In the cases of the other sub-categories, the proof is similar.) Denote the subsequence $(x_{n_i},y_{n_i})$.

Since $f(X,0)$ is a continuous function of $X$ and given that $f(0,0)=0$, choose any positive real constant $\eta>0$ such that $|f(\eta,0)|<\frac{1}{2}r$. The specific value of $\eta$ doesn't matter much.

Think about the values of $f(\eta,y_{n_i})$. Because $x_{n_i}$ tends to $0$, at some stage $N$ we have that $x_{n_i}<\eta$ for all $i>N$. Therefore, $f(\eta,y_{n_i})\geq f(x_{n_i},y_{n_i})\geq r$ for all $i>N$. This contradicts the fact that $f(\eta,Y)$ is continuous as a function of $Y$ and therefore $f(\eta,y_{n_i})$ should converge to $f(\eta,0)\leq \frac{r}{2}$.